# "Correct" .Net Datatype for storing 0.0-1.0

Tags: .net, types

I use the 0.0-1.0 range in a lot of places. Some examples include:

Reporting progress (0=Started, 0.5=50% Complete, 1=Done), comparison between 2 objects (0=no match, 0.95 = very similar, 1=identical), etc.

I prefer to avoid integers in any fixed range (0-100) as a) the 100 in the example feels arbitrary and b) what about non-discrete values like 12.5?

At present, I use a double and force myself to the convention that `0<=x<=1`

This works fine but I'm now writing an app which supports plugins and the plugins report processing progress. At present, this is reported by a double and the app throws an exception if the value is out of range. What I really want is a data type that implicitly limits the value to anything in the range 0-1 or Min-Max or similar

NB: I'm aware that all data types will have a maximum resolution. I'm also aware that an integer 0-100 is probably close enough in most cases - But what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never found a good answer tot his but have settled for using an integer in the range `0<=x<=Integer.MaxValue`.

This isn't ideal as it's not particularly human-readable but it does implicitly enforce a valid range and give more than enough resolution for most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enums.  Otherwise your code will be littered with [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

Comment: How does an enum solve this? Uing an enum to represent max range? That feels as bad as just letting the plugin developer try a value and exception if hey got it wrong...

Comment: Enums make perfect sense for the examples you gave  (0=Started, 1=Done) (0=no match, 1=identical).  I don't think you made it very clear if what you really want is ranges between those two limits.

Comment: I thought `0<=x<=1` was pretty clear. In any case, I meant eg 0 = started, .25 = 25% done, .75 = 75% done, 1 = 100% done.

Answer (score 0):

If a plugin reports progress in a range Min to Max you can convert this to a range 0-1 as follows:

```
((double) progressValue + (double) Min) / (double) (Max - Min)
```

Or if as is more likely the progress value is in the range 0 to Max, this simplifies to:

```
(double) progressValue / (double) (Max)
```

Your convention of 0<=x<=1 for progress reporting is reasonable enough if you're consistent with it.  Personally I generally prefer to use 0<=x<=100 as this is what is used by the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method.

For progress reporting using integer values is generally precise enough - a user probably doesn't care much about the difference between 12.5% complete and 13% complete.

As for your other example, I would also generally use a range of 0 to 1 to represent 0% to 100% - then format it as a percentage using the "P" format specifier.

Comment: Thank for the info, I'm perfectly happy manipulating one range into another - that' not the problem, I'm looking for a data type with an implicit range

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different use cases here:

1. Progress: 0 (started) to 1 (done). Use a float or double. This can be used to scale a progress bar or can be presented as a percentage (or both).
2. Comparison: use a boolean (true = identical, false = not identical)
3. In the case of your plug-in situation, I would create an interface like `IProgressValue` or something. Include methods for setting the value from different input types.

Comment: I don't believe I do... 1) What happens if someone provides a value of 1.5? 2) perhaps I was unclear but this is also a sliding scale (0.95 - objects are very similar but not identical) 3) I don't see how that would help - My issue is that I'm looking for a type with an implicit range

Comment: 1)You would obviously also have to validate the settings and not permit a value >1. 2) You're right, you didn't make that clear; please update the question with that information. 3) This would isolate the plug-ins from the details of the implementation of your type, permitting you to use different implementations under different circumstances.

Comment: 1) Already mentioned in OP as the current method. 2) I've added an intermediate value, thanks. 3) I use interfaces everywhere but still don't see what you're getting at. Would you mind giving an example of a method in the interface. All I can see is `void SetProgress(double Progress)` or similar - which is just the same problem?

Comment: You're right. Since your #2 is a range, it's pretty much identical to #1